# Need help with expressions like "It is going to be like this..."

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

Consider this expression:

> If you don't make an effort for this, It is going to be very difficult

Instead of the expression "it is going be difficult", I want to elaborate what the repercussions will be:

> If you don't make an effort for this, **it is going like this, that even if you have a decent profile and resume, no one will consider you.**

The second sounds wrong to me. Specifically, the **like this that** part sounds odd to me.  Can anyone help with this expression and point out what the correct version is?

Answer (score 3):

All that *it is going to be...* does is spell out the consequences of not making an effort: *it's going to be very difficult.*

So, you just need to spell out different consequences:

> If you don't make an effort for this, no-one will consider you.

You can add your parenthetical clause in too:

> If you don't make an effort for this, even if you have a decent profile and resume, no-one will consider you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two unidiomatic expressions here.

1. With expressions like *try*, *attempt*, *make an effort*, *for* is generally used to introduce the beneficiary of the effort: *Make this effort for your children*. Better uses would be *make an effort **to VERB*** or *make an effort **to achieve this***. It may even be that you don't need the phrase at all:

   > If you don't make this effort, ...
2. English has lots of ways of saying *the result will be*, but *it is going like this* is not one of them. Here are some possibilities:

   - ..., what will happen is ...
   - ..., the consequence will be ...
   - ..., you will find that ...

   But the simplest way in this particular case is to skip that phrase altogether and go right to the result:

   > If you don't make this effort, no one will consider you, even if you have a decent profile and resume.